# Merge 2 onclick actions (Javascript) and trigger them with a single button

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have to buttons, each with an onclick function but I want to merge them into 1.

**Button 1: Show a message that things are ok**

```
<button type="button" onclick="UIkit.notification({message: 'This is an alert'})">Click me</button>
```

**Button 2: Add a product to cart (WooCommerce)**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420'">Click me</a>
```

How can I merge those 2 onlick actions into 1 single button click?

Many tnx.

PS. This doesn't seem to work (product gets added but message is not shown):

```
<script>
    function action1(){
        UIkit.notification({message: 'Notification message'});
    }
     
    function action2(){
        window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420';
    }
</script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="action1();action2();">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new function where you execute both actions. Then pass this new function to your button.

```
<script>
    function action1(){
        UIkit.notification({message: 'Notification message'});
    }
     
    function action2(){
        window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420';
    }
     
    function doActions(){
        action1();
        action2();
    }
</script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="doActions();">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Tnx. Your code works but the 'Notification message' disappears right away (normally stays there for 5 seconds) although I never leave the page. Any idea why? Adding the product to cart works.

Comment: @YorlinqNL It's because you redirect right away. To prevent this you could add a delay before you execute action2. This can be done with something like [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign more than one handler to `.onclick`, but you can do it with `.addEventListener(event, handler)` like this:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const link = document.querySelector('a');

function action1(){
  UIkit.notification({message: 'Notification message'});
}
 
function action2(){
   window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420';
}

button.addEventListeneer('click', action1);
button.addEventListeneer('click', action2);
link.addEventListeneer('click', action1);
link.addEventListeneer('click', action2);
```

Comment: Tnx. What would the html button output would be to trigger this function?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, it is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with one click only like

```
async function actions(){
    await UIkit.notification({message: 'Notification message'});
    window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420';
}
```

Comment: Tnx. Your code works but the 'Notification message' disappears right away (normally stays there for 5 seconds) although I never leave the page. Any idea why? Adding the product to cart works.

Comment: you can add a delay function to solve it like                                            `setTimeout(()=>{ window.location.href='https://chatsales.nl/pakketten/doe-het-zelf?add-to-cart=420'; },5000);`